# What does it mean for the difference $V(\overline{x}_L -dx) -V(\overline{x}_L)$ to be of the second order in $dx$

Tags: derivatives, terminology

What does it mean for the difference $V(\overline{x}_L -dx) -V(\overline{x}_L)$ to be of the second order in $dx$, where $dx$ is some tiny increment of $x$?

What we know about $V$:

- $V(z) = U(z) - c\cdot z$, some $z$
- $V(\cdot)$ is maximized at
  $\overline{x}_L$.
- $U(0) = 0$

If necessary, I am okay with the answer assuming that $U(\cdot)$ is increasing.

The reasoning for the difference $V(\overline{x}_L -dx) -V(\overline{x}_L)$ to be of the second order in $dx$ is:

> Since V is maximized at  $\overline{x}_L$, it must be that the
>   difference $V(\overline{x}_L -dx) -V(\overline{x}_L)$ is of second
>   order in $dx$

So to restate the question, I don't know what "of second order in $dx$" means here. There are no time indexes, so it's not something like that. I thought perhaps it means that $dx$ enters the difference non-linearly, but without knowing more I don't see how we can say this...

Edit: if it makes difference, the terminology is from a source written in the mid-80s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got it... If we taylor expand the function $V(x)$ around $\overline{x}_L$, because the first derivative is $0$ (because maximum), then the first derivative does not enter the approximation but the second derivative does, hence this is a second order effect.

I am not sure why we would be taylor expanding, though... If I take a wild guess, perhaps because we are looking at an infinitesimal difference, we taylor expand the difference, and perhaps the first derivative of the difference is still $0$ since we are infinitesimally closed to the maximum, and thus same logic? I haven't thought this through though, so I can quite possibly be incorrect.